# pm2 start config.js file which only starts some of the processes

Tags: javascript, pm2

So currently we have a config.js file which exports a list of {apps} which pm2 takes and starts up (pm2 start core.config.js).

However some of these must not actually be started. In other words it must start in a downed state.
This is cause if a client manually sets certain services(processes) to be off, pm2 must not start them but they should still be visible on pm2 status but as "Stopped" or "disabled"

[image: pm2 status with a process down]

Example would be the integrationMicroService in the image

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski . I've tried excluding the ones that shouldnt be starting up in the config.js file however the problem there, is then it wont display on the pm2 status at all. which will fek around with our front end.
The other thing i tried was adding another config.js script which basically automatically runs after the first script but instead stops the processes from running. This second method was my best bet but the processes that shouldnt run, should not even begin from the first script cause could be bad for the clients

Comment: Someone recommended I somehow edit or use the dump.pm2 file but not sure how exactly in terms of my issue

Comment: Can you try pm2 monit and see what you get?